# How quickly find we find a primitive root of unity in $\mathbb{F}_{p^z}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, algorithms, finite-fields, roots-of-unity

If we are working in a finite field of integers adjoined with $z$ values, we have $\mathbb{F}_{p^z}$, assuming that we constructed the field correctly.  How quickly can we find a value, $\omega$, that is a $p^z - 1$ primitive root of unity?

**AN APPROACH**

@ACL's approach, taken from [this MathOverflow answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/115561/24942) is essentially as follows:

(1)  Factor $p^z - 1$, as a product of primes to powers.

(2)  For each prime power $q^r$, find a value $v$ whose power $v^{(p-1) / q}$ is not equivalent to $1$.

(3)  Multiply all values $v^{(p-1) / q}$ together, for each prime power.

This should give an element $\omega$ with the desired properties.

There is also another approach, by Derek Holt, found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/951815/2626).  The difference is that in this question, we are working with a specific ring, namely a finite field.

**A QUESTION**

Knowing that we're working in the specialized setting of a finite field with $p^z$ elements, can we find a primitive $p^z - 1$ root of unity faster?